# Modal pop up issue; background is not fading and pop up does not appears on whole browser lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

[image]

```
<div aria-hidden="false" aura:id="newClientSectionId" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-modal--large slds-fade-in-open slds-hide" 
     style="width: 60%; margin: auto; ">
    <div class="slds-m-bottom--xx-large"></div>
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" onclick="{!c.showModalBox}">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Create Opportunity</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
            <div class="slds-m-top--xx-large"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__footer"> <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.showModalBox}">Cancel</button>
            <ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.saveOpportunity}" label="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open slds-hide" id="backGroundSectionId"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
//for showing modal
$A.util.removeClass(component.find("newClientSectionId"), "slds-hide");
$A.util.removeClass(component.find("backGroundSectionId"), "slds-hide");
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS.slds-hide {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: How are you showing the modal.

Comment: i am using add and remove class for showing and hiding modal

Comment: Are you enclosing your code in `<div class="slds"></div>` ?

Comment: @CasparHarmer yes

Comment: Ahh. The old sf header issue. Give me a few I have a hacky workaround

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to make the id on the backdrop an `aura:id`

Change `id="backGroundSectionId"`

To `aura:id="backGroundSectionId"`

Comment: Thanks i have changed that, fading option is resolved. But pop up does not appears on whole browser lightning page

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what is happening and describe what you want to happen

Answer (score 1):

[Full implementation Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173273/how-to-overwrite-app-css-styles-with-lightning-components)

**NOTE** this is a hack, it *may* break between releases due to CSS class changes and works as of Winter 17 but

To enable the backdrop and the modal to extend beyond and in front of the SF tabs and header add the following to your component:

```
<style>
    {!v.modalStyle}
</style>
```

Then in your code where you open the modal add this:

```
component.set("v.modalStyle", ".forceStyle .viewport .oneHeader {z-index:0; }
 .slds-global-header_container {position: static;} .forceStyle.desktop 
.viewport{overflow:hidden}");
```

Then when you hide the modal use this code to clear the style css

```
component.set("v.modalStyle", "");
```

Comment: Thanks. But still it is not working. Pop up appears in the same way.

Comment: @EffatNaaz - Well I can tell you it works fine for me and without it the modal is behind the SF tabs and header. Use the Dom inspector to see if you can find the elements and manually change the position to static and see if that does not. If so then maybe you need to adjust the selectors a but in your case

Comment: @Effat - any luck on this?

Comment: @Eric - when i open the dom inspector and manually change it to below even then it doesnt really hide the SF tabs...forceStyle.desktop 
.viewport{overflow:hidden}");

Comment: @user2945545 there are 3 CSS changes that are made in the answer not just the overflow hidden

Comment: @Eric - am able to manually edit and achieve it but not with below                                                                                                                       component.set("v.cssStyle", ".forceStyle .viewport.oneHeader.desktop {z  index:0} .forceStyle.desktop .viewport{overflow:hidden}");                                                                                                                   <aura:attribute name="cssStyle" type="String" />    <style>{!v.cssStyle}</style>

Answer (score 0):

The addition of `<style>` tags wont go through security from upcoming component versions(42) onwards. As an alternative we can use `aura:unescapedHTML` tag

```
<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.modalStyle}"/>
```

> Controller:

```
//To hide
component.set("v.modalStyle", "");

//To imply the styles
component.set("v.modalStyle", "<style>.forceStyle .viewport .oneHeader {z-index:0; }
 .slds-global-header_container {position: static;} .forceStyle.desktop 
.viewport{overflow:hidden}</style>");
```

We have discussed this with salesforce and they have given thumbs up for using this hack. Of course you need to ensure that you are not exposing sensitive information here as mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_unescapedHtml.htm).