# Can modal Lightning components be displayed on the very top?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button-overrides, modal

I have overridden the standard New object action with my custom Lightning Component Bundle. I am using the modal CSS styles as well as the modal backdrop to mimic a native modal dialog in SF. The problem is, on low-res screens my the top portion of my modal dialog goes under the SF header.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <p class="slds-text-heading--medium">Custom Page</p>
        </header>

        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
            <!-- BODY -->
        </div>

        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancel}"/>
            <lightning:button label="Save" onclick="{!c.save}"/>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Given the way components are isolated from each other I can't use z-index. Is what I want to do possible at all?

My last resort is padding the top using the CSS @media query but I'd rather find a better solution.

Comment: A better answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173273/how-to-overwrite-app-css-styles-with-lightning-components/173293#173293

Comment: @Eric Your proposed workaround to the last topic was excellent!! This would be a duplicate to some extent, except, I am working with a standard-button-override (as opposed to clicking a button to open the modal dialog). I used your script in my init() function and it worked beautifully. So the moral of the story is, I *could* use z-index but only during component init.

Comment: could you put your workaround as an answer to specifically relate to this question? Interested in seeing the issue and fix

Answer (score 1):

I used the idea in the workaround provided in [this SFSE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173273/how-to-overwrite-app-css-styles-with-lightning-components/173293#173293) and tweaked it to fit my use-case. Essentially I am able to tamper with the z-index during component initialization:

Component markup:

```
<aura:attribute name="modalStyle" type="String"/>
<style>
    {!v.modalStyle}
</style>
```

Component controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.modalStyle", ".forceStyle .viewport .oneHeader {z-index:0; } .slds-global-header_container {position: static;} .forceStyle.desktop .viewport{overflow:hidden}");
}
```