# Overide app.css style in salesforce lightning in Summer 18 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, style

We are trying to override the app.css in a custom lightning component embed in quick action to increase the width of the quick action screen. For this we are try to use the `'<style></style>'`. But it not supported. However tried to use the `<head></head>` tag. Still it didn't worked out. What is the alternate or workaround for the same ?
[how to overwrite app.css styles with lightning components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173273/how-to-overwrite-app-css-styles-with-lightning-components)
Above link we tried which was working in the 2017 release but currently not working.

Comment: have to tried to upload the css in static resource and then add that static resource in component? try this?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the following stylesheet as the static resource and include that in your lightning component.

```
.cuf-content{
   padding:0 !important;
}
.slds-p-around--medium{
   padding:0 !important;
}
.slds-modal__container{        
   width:80% !important;
   max-width:80% !important;
}
.slds-modal__content{
   overflow-y:hidden !important;
   height:unset !important;
   max-height:unset !important;
}
```

> You can also update the style using jQuery on the component load.