# LWC Modal popup in lightning console is not coming full screen

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, css

LWC lightning pop up is not getting displayed in Full screen inside lightning console. Please find below screenshot. [image: Modal Issue]

And also second part of the question is when picklist is having more values, it is going behind footer. So user is not able to select the lower picklist values.

P.S : I have already referred [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173273/how-to-overwrite-app-css-styles-with-lightning-components) question. But since it is implemented in Aura I was not able to understand it properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. It might be helpful to post your lwc code to give you specific guidance.

Comment: @Kris Goncalves - Sure sir. But the issue is with all the modals irrespective of modal code. Modal backdrop is not going beyond the case number header section.